# JBoss with JTS; XA or local datasource?

Tags: jakarta-ee, jboss

I want to do a distributed transaction. I have 3 application servers with JTS (Transaction Manager) enabled.
Each app server is connected to a db. 
One app server calls 2 EJBs of the other app servers. I want all the calls executed
in a transaction.

The question: Should the app server's (JBoss) data sources be local or xa?

All application servers have a Transaction Manager. All TM talk each other with JTS (OTS). So they don't connect directly to remote dbs. So why should remote dbs be XA?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must use **container managed transactions**, and you must use **XA data sources** to get distributed transactions.

So the first application server creates the global transaction, and the **transaction context** is propagated into the EJBs of the other application servers (it won't be propagated in case of bean managed transactions). In those methods, their connection from the XA data source is **enlisted** in the global transaction.

When the method in the first application server is completed, the global transaction **commits** all units of work (in all application servers). If there is an error, the global transaction is **rolled back**, and so all units of work are discarded.

So the JTS do not "talk" to each other, the global transaction is coordinated by the first application server only.

Comment: So are JTS transaction managers required on the appliction servers except for the 1st one? (or can they be just JTA?)

Comment: From a logical point of view, the JTS is only required on the 1st one AFAIK. I can't speak for the actual implementation, possibly the real 2nd phase commit on the remote systems is done by that local JTS on behalf of the primary JTS. JTA is probably required on all nodes, because the container will use it implicitly to enlist XA resources in the global transaction.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I am just reading the JTS spec [link] (http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/jcp/7309-jts-1.0-spec-oth-JSpec/jts1_0-spec.pdf), p. 11, but it doesn't say how the Transaction Manager connects to Application Servers (it only says the vice versa). I guess it uses JTS (OTS) to speak to the Transaction Manager of another Application Server.

Answer (score 0):

If all calls should be preformed or nothing, you should use xa-datasources, otherwise rollback in one of component will not force rollback on other parties.